# cannot call anything from different file error LNK2005 and fatal error LNK1169

Tags: c++

I've tried to link other file that contain function and call it in main file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test1.cpp"
    int main()     // main.cpp file
    {
        fun();
        return 0;
    }

#include <iostream>   //test1.cpp file
void fun()
{
    std::cout << "text";
}
```

And... the output gives me that two errors:

```
1>test1.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl fun(void)" (?fun@@YAXXZ) already defined in main.obj

fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>Done building project "proj.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: linker error means the problem is not in the code but in how you build it. How do you build it?

Comment: Well, simply I just create an empty project, then making .cpp files in /source files dir and simply press 'local windows debugger'.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 And yet, lo and behold, the problem is in the code.

Answer (score 3):

You should not include a .cpp file in another one. If you do this, your function gets declared twice (this is the cause of your link error).

To achieve your goal, use a header file (.h) in which you'll declare only the prototype of your function and include this header in the main.cpp.

Comment: The problem is the function gets **defined** twice, multiple declarations aren't an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is to use 3 files:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test1.h" // notice the .h file extension instead of .cpp
int main()     // main.cpp file
{
    fun();
    return 0;
}
```

test1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
void fun()
{
    std::cout << "text";
}
```

And finally, a separate .h file to bridge the two together:
test1.h

```
// a function declaration
void fun();
```

For more information on this, you can read more about [header](http://www.math.uaa.alaska.edu/%7Eafkjm/csce211/handouts/SeparateCompilation.pdf) [files](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/header-files-in-c-cpp-and-its-uses/).